# Is it possible not to generate ALL_BUILD project in cmake?

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui

I don't need ALL_BUILD subproject, can I avoid generating it? Thanx.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[CMake Issue #16979: "ALL_BUILD target being generated"](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16979):

> The `ALL_BUILD` target corresponds to CMake's notion of the "all" target, equivalent to make all with makefile generators.  This is different from "Build Solution" behavior due to idiosyncrasies in how the VS IDE deals with inter-vcxproj dependencies.
>
> There is no way to suppress the `ALL_BUILD` target.  It must exist for commands like `cmake --build`. to be able to build the "all" target by default.

So you can't avoid it - as with @arrowd answer - but there are some things in CMake that can influence the usage/appearance (on IDE generators like Visual Studio) of it:

1. When you activate global [`USE_FOLDERS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/USE_FOLDERS.html) property

   ```
    set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
   ```

   the generic targets `ALL_BUILD`, `ZERO_CHECK`, `INSTALL`, `PACKAGE` and `RUN_TESTS` will be grouped into the `CMakePredefinedTargets` folder (or whichever name is given in global [`PREDEFINED_TARGETS_FOLDER`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/PREDEFINED_TARGETS_FOLDER.html) property).

   [image]
2. The global variables `CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_ALL_DEPENDENCY` and `CMAKE_SKIP_PACKAGE_ALL_DEPENDENCY` do suppress otherwise automatically generated dependencies for `INSTALL` or `PACKAGE` to the `ALL_BUILD` target.
3. The global [`VS_STARTUP_PROJECT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/VS_STARTUP_PROJECT.html) property can be used to change the default startup project name to something other than the `ALL_BUILD` or "first project not in sub-folder" targets.

**References**

- [What are ALL_BUILD and ZERO_CHECK and do I need them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27175754/what-are-all-build-and-zero-check-and-do-i-need-them)
- [How to skip dependency on all for package target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43609677/how-to-skip-dependency-on-all-for-package-target)
- [No CMakePredefinedTargets when using solution folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36149962/no-cmakepredefinedtargets-when-using-solution-folders)

Comment: is there a way to make "current selection" the default start project?

Answer (score 2):

It corresponds to the `all` make target, so, no, you can't avoid generating it. You can delete it from the solution manually, though.